# How to get EVENT based on startday, using BETWEEN

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that get all events ordering by Startdate, and i define startday as $today.

but this query didn't take events that start yestarday and that endday is tomorow.

how can i make my query to use BETWEEN ?

my query

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, `wp_mec_dates` AS mecd, wp_icl_translations WHERE wp_posts.ID = mecd.post_id and post_status='publish' AND wp_icl_translations.language_code='$lang' AND dstart>'$startday' and  wp_posts.ID = wp_icl_translations.element_id ORDER BY dstart LIMIT 0,6
```

startdate is `$startday = date("Y-m-d");`

EDIT : with documentation & help, i'm here now :

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_mec_dates AS mecd, wp_icl_translations WHERE wp_posts.ID = mecd.post_id and post_status='publish' AND wp_icl_translations.language_code='$lang' AND ($startday BETWEEN dstart AND dend)AND  wp_posts.ID = wp_icl_translations.element_id ORDER BY dstart LIMIT 0,6
```

but it return 0 results.
Any help will be apreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution <3

Used WHERE '$startday' BETWEEN dstart AND dend

plus : OR dstart >= '$startday'

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts, wp_mec_dates AS mecd, wp_icl_translations WHERE wp_posts.ID = mecd.post_id and post_status='publish' AND wp_icl_translations.language_code='$lang' AND ('$startday' BETWEEN dstart AND dend OR dstart >= '$startday') AND  wp_posts.ID = wp_icl_translations.element_id ORDER BY dstart LIMIT 0,6
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
WHERE dstart BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'
```

Comment: hello, what do i set as "enddate" ?

Comment: for example: $startdate = '2019-07-16' AND $enddate = '2019-07-18'

Comment: yes, but i didn't know enddate ;-) perhaps, i found a solution investigating your idee. See my answear.